# Can Anyone explains how this where statement works in the query(not commented out) and how we are getting same result as above query without group by?

Tags: sql, subquery

```
/*
SELECT countries.name AS country, COUNT(*) AS cities_num
  FROM cities
    INNER JOIN countries
    ON countries.code = cities.country_code
GROUP BY country
ORDER BY cities_num DESC, country
LIMIT 9;
*/

SELECT name AS country,
  -- Subquery
  (SELECT count(*)
   FROM cities
   WHERE countries.code = cities.country_code) AS cities_num
FROM countries
ORDER BY cities_num DESC, country
LIMIT 9;
```

I was expecting the sub query to return the value of the count of all the cities across the countries and if that happens I was expecting in the lower query an error but it gives me the same result as the upper query that is count of cities for each country.

Answer (score 0):

The query which you are referring as subquery is actually a classic example of [Co-Related](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/subqueries/correlated-subqueries-using-aliases.php) Subquery.

```
SELECT name AS country,
  -- Subquery
  (SELECT count(*)
   FROM cities
   WHERE countries.code = cities.country_code) AS cities_num
FROM countries
ORDER BY cities_num DESC, country
LIMIT 9;
```

Co-related sub-query is a sub-query which **gets executed once for each record in the outer table**. You can identify a co-related subquery by where condition which will always reference a column from outer table.

```
countries.code = cities.country_code
```

Countries is outer table and cities is inner table.

If you want to count all cities in the country using subquery, just removed the above condition.